# any possibility to write own functions in SQL (user defined function SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

is there any possibility to write own functions in SQL. I mean with the own function something like in Mathematica or C that I have a variable or couple of variables and after certain operations I get an Output which could be everything.
Or probably there is a language which can be applied to do that within SQL.

Comment: Have a look at stored procedures. May work with SQL Server or Postgresql or whatever db you use.

Comment: Yes of course this is possible. What exactly is your question? In Postgres you can write functions in PL/pgSQL, C, JavaScript, Python, Perl and others. This is all explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-programming.html

Comment: Thanks a lot at first. I will look at Postgres. I want to write a function getting an schema and does some calculations and give a table back.

Comment: "*write a function getting a schema*" does not make any sense (at least to me). A schema is a collection of database objects (tables, views, procedures). So "getting a schema" doesn't really make sense in the context of calling a function. Why would you want to pass all tables, views, materialized views, indexes, triggers, types, domains, rules and functions to a function?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is related to `SQL Server` (i don't know anything about `Postgres`).

in `SQL Server` you can write stored functions and stored procedures by using T-SQL.

[Microsoft documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx)

For more powerful functions you can also use MS .NET technology to extend the `SQL Server`. Start point may be here:
[Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has its own procedural language [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql.html). You can also create functions [using SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html), as well as several other languages like [python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-funcs.html), [perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plperl-funcs.html) and [others](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/server-programming.html).

Answer (score 1):

My answer are Microsoft SQL Server .

Yes you can write own function in Sql server .

```
Create function Function 
as
@id int
begin 
Select * from Employee where emp_id=@id
end
```